# css gradient not rendering well on mobile phone

Tags: css, css-gradients

I created a site with a gradient in the hero-section by using 3 stacked divs with something like

`background: linear-gradient( to right bottom, purple, blue);`

and I'm seeing a strange behavior in mobile. It should look like this:

[image: The hero section as it is supposed to look]

But it looks like this instead:

[image: The hero section as it actually looks]

You can reproduce it in this codepen: https://codepen.io/marnau/pen/GRxjBzM. When I open it on desktop I can see the gradient. On mobile I can't.

This site is where I'm having the problem: https://acupunt.cat on mobile.
The problem occurs with both linear-gradient and radial-gradient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also read [why offsite links aren't good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code). If your site gets updated, this question becomes useless to future visitors.

Comment: I visited on browser sized at an iphone as well as on my mobile phone and the site appeared to function as intended for both.

Comment: Thanks for testing @JDawwgy. I'm having no trouble on dev tools sized at mobile, only on a real phone. It might be some silly css problem. See if you can reproduce it in the codepen on mobile. Thanks!